# Click once application Deployment - Installation Error

Tags: deployment, clickonce

I have created winform application using .Net Framework 4.5
I have created click once deployment package for it. But when i install it on server it gives me error as below[image]

and the error upon clicking Details buttons shown as

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Users******\Downloads\Publish******.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading file:///C:/Users/******/Downloads/Publish/Application Files/********_1_0_0_3/*******.dll.deploy did not succeed.
        + Access to the path 'C:\Users**********\AppData\Local\Temp\2\Deployment\********.dll' is denied.

Comment: any solutions found?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem on occasion. ...\Temp\2... seems to be a default folder for doing stuff. My clickonce deployment was getting blocked by a test run in Selenium using the same location to store its test logs.

Check if the location is being used by other processes to store files while they are working or see if you can clear the folder before starting the update (if you do an update in code vs just clicking the *.appref-ms file).

Also note that ...\Temp\2 can show up as a file instead of a folder thereby blocking any use of it as a folder.